# Passing an argument when starting new QThread() in PyQt

Tags: python, multithreading, pyqt

I have a multi-threaded application written in Python in which one thread "takes care" of the GUI, and the other is the worker thread. However, the worker thread has two main functions (or so to say two main jobs), and I need to tell the run function which job exactly to do.

So what I had in mind was to create a run function in the worker thread which will take one parameter (save for "self). The parameter will either be "create" or upload. Without further ado, here's the somewhat-code that I have so far:

GUI.py

```
class GUI(QMainWindow):
  def __init__(self, parent=None):
    super, etc
    self.worker = worker.Worker()

  def create(self):         
     self.worker.start()

  def upload(self):
     self.worker.start()
```

Worker.py

```
class Worker(QThread):
  def __init__(self, parent=None):
    super, etc

  def run(self):
     self.create_data() # OR   self.upload_data(), depends
```

So the question is, how can I tell worker.start() which function I want it to perform? I realize one could directly use worker.run() method, but I was told by the "Rapid GUI development with PyQT" *never* to call worker.run() directly, and always to use worker.start().

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The `start` method of `QThread` doesn't accept arguments. However, you've inherited `QThread` so you're free to customize it at will. So, to implement what you want, just pass arguments into the constructor of `Worker`.

Here's your code sample slightly modified to show this in action:

```
class Worker(QThread):
  def __init__(self, do_create_data=True, parent=None):
    super(QThread, self).__init__()
    self.do_create_data = create_data

  def run(self):
     if self.create_data:
         self.create_data()
     else:
         self.upload_data(), depends
```

Comment: @Deusdies upload_data() is a function of the same thread? How can send a line as argument?

Comment: Can you please explain what `super, etc` means ?

Comment: @Nateshbhat 
`super(QThread, self).__init__()`. I will change the original post.

Answer (score 1):

Eli Bendersky's answer is correct, however the order of arguments appears wrong.

If you call the Worker class like this:

The argument order that worked for me:

```
def __init__(self, parent=None, do_create_data=True):
```

The order shown in Eli Bendersky's answer produced this error message for me:

```
TypeError: QThread(QObject parent=None): argument 1 has unexpected type 'str'
```

Not sure why, but I'm sure someone can help explain.

Comment: Put `parent` parameter as the last optional  parameter. Since it's not used, you can even get rid of it.