# Error when passing argument to QThread subclass in PyQt5

Tags: python-3.x, qthread, pyqt5

I'm new in PyQt5, there is something wrong when I tried to pass arguments to a QThread subclass. Here is the code:

```py
class DrClientThread(QtCore.QThread):
    def __int__(self, server, username, password):
        QtCore.QThread.__init__(self)
        self.server = server
        self.username = username
        self.password = password

    def run(self):
        print(self.username, self.password, self.server)

class DrCOM_UI(Ui_Login_Dialog):
    def __init__(self, dialog):
        Ui_Login_Dialog.__init__(self)
        self.setupUi(dialog)
        self.login_btn.clicked.connect(self.login_and_keep_alive)
        ...
    def login_and_keep_alive(self):        
        server, username, password = self.write_data_before_login()
        self.drclient = DrClientThread(server, username, password)
        self.drclient.start()
```

When I run the code, it gave me the exception:

```py
in login_and_keep_alive
self.mydrclient = DrClientThread(server, username, password)
builtins.TypeError: QThread(QObject parent=None): argument 1 has unexpected type 'str'
```

I did some google work, and read almost every question on stackoverflow related to this problem, but I can't find out a solution. Actually, I want to do like this: [How can I pass arguments to QThread Worker class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25413743/how-can-i-pass-arguments-to-qthread-worker-class)

Anyone can help me?

Comment: You have `__int__` instead of `__init__`

Comment: Thanks, I need be more careful. But, now, there is a new error:QtCore.QThread.__init__()

builtins.TypeError: self must not be None How can i fix it?

Answer (score 0):

```
class DrClientThread(QtCore.QThread):
    def __int__(self, server, username, password):
        QtCore.QThread.__init__(self)
        self.server = server
        self.username = username
        self.password = password

    def run(self):
        print(self.username, self.password, self.server)

class DrCOM_UI(Ui_Login_Dialog):
    def __init__(self, dialog):
        Ui_Login_Dialog.__init__(self)
        self.setupUi(dialog)
        self.login_btn.clicked.connect(self.login_and_keep_alive)
        ...
    def login_and_keep_alive(self):        
        server, username, password = self.write_data_before_login()
        self.drclient = DrClientThread(self, server, username, password) # <<-----
        self.drclient.start()
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Comment: Make sure to include a more in-depth explanation on what your code is doing and where the problem occurs. Showing your written code is a great addition to the clarity of the post, but you should pair it with written text explaining how it works, and some info about pinpointing the bug in order to write a great question which will attract great answers.